# Using a series of sequences from string in a FOR loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

On linux command line using bash, I am reading a variable from the command line

```
./testRange.sh -s '{5..7} {13..15} {20..50..10}'
```

into a variable

```
while [ -n "$1" ]; do 
    case "$1" in
        -s) 
            range="$2"
            echo -e "Range string: $range"
            shift
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

NOTE: if the way the series of sequences is being inputed on the command line is problematic, I would accept other *command-line only* (no files) methods.

I want to use the variable in a for loop, but following the sequence from the command line. This is where I am running into problems. I cannot figure out how to convert the variable into a usable sequence in the `FOR` loop. I would like the output to look like

```
Current sequence value: 5
Current sequence value: 6
Current sequence value: 7
Current sequence value: 13
Current sequence value: 14
...
```

**This does not work:**

```
for i in ${range}; do
    echo -e "Current sequence value: $i"
done
```

Can you help me figure out what does?

Comment: Use `./testRange.sh -s {5..7} {13..15} {20..50..10}` without `'` and in your script `for i in $@; do echo "$i"; done`?

Comment: This is an example, but I am using far more parameters than just the `-s` in the real program, so I can't use the full array itself.

Comment: Try `for i in $(eval echo $range); do ...` Probably there are simpler solutions but at least it works for me.

Comment: I found a similar solution a few minutes ago. Thanks, @Abelisto.

Comment: In my solution less quotes ;) Good luck!

Comment: It was posted simultaneously. I have no problem with convergent evolution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to convert the variable into a usable sequence in the FOR loop

Well, it's not going to be simple, but let's do it.

Basically we want to:

- write a function
- that takes an argument consisting of space separated

  - elements enclosed in `{` `}`
  - with number like `start..stop` or `start..stop..increment`
  - that denote a sequence
- and that function should output

  - the generated sequence

That would be something like:

```
gen() {
   tr ' ' '\n' <<<"$1" |
   sed 's/[{}\.]/ /g' |
   while IFS=' ' read -r a b c; do
      if [ -z "$c" ]; then 
          seq "$a" "$b"
      else
          seq "$a" "$c" "$b"
      fi
   done
}
```

And that function run like:

```
gen '{5..7} {13..15} {20..50..10}'
```

outputs:

```
5
6
7
13
14
15
20
30
40
50
```

Validating the input is left as an exercise to the reader.

The following looks like a slightly better version of the function, with error handling. It uses `\+` in `sed` with is a GNU extension.

```
gen() {
   if ! tmp=$(
            tr ' ' '\n' <<<"$1" |
        sed '
                /^{\([0-9]\+\)\.\.\([0-9]\+\)}$/s//\1 1 \2/
                /^{\([0-9]\+\)\.\.\([0-9]\+\)\.\.\([0-9]\+\)}$/s//\1 \3 \2/
                t
                q 1
            ')
    then
        echo "wrong input" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
    <<<"$tmp" xargs -n3 seq
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but I made it work using `"$(eval echo "$range")"` (see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59013814/516537 ). Is there a reason for concern in using the `eval` solution over a function?

Comment: [Eval command and security issues](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)

Comment: Good point. My use is internal, but there is no reason for dangerous solutions. I'll post a comment/warning on my solution.

Comment: This assumes only two (first..last) and three (first..incr..last), but `seq` does allow a single number sequence as well (last).

Comment: Due to the complexity, I would like an easier way to input a *series of sequences* on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This solution works, but is dangerous to your linux health. It is easy to have the `eval` run arbitrary code. Please read [this article](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) and find a solution some other way (like [@KamilCuk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59013830/516537), who helped me understand the concern).

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ -n "$1" ]; do 
    case "$1" in
        -s) 
            range="$2"
            echo -e "Range string: $range"
            shift
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done

rangeProcessed="$(eval echo "$range")"
echo -e "Processed range: $rangeProcessed"

for i in $rangeProcessed; do
    echo -e "Current sequence value: $i"
done
```

Comment: If input string doesn't come from user there is nothing wrong with this solution. Although it is true for most cases that *eval is evil*, this mindset also leads less experienced programmers to [cargo-cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). Instead of avoiding `eval` no matter what; learn how it works, understand its caveats and avoid when necessary

Answer (score 1):

Would you try the following:

testRange.sh:

```
while [ -n "$1" ]; do
    case "$1" in
        -s)
            read -ra list <<< "$2"
            for l in "${list[@]}"; do
#               l="${l//[{\}]/}"
                l="${l//[^0-9.]/}"        # sanitize the input
                declare -a 'ary+=({'"$l"'})'
            done
            for i in "${ary[@]}"; do
                echo -e "Range string: $i"
            done
            shift
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

```
./testRange.sh -s '{5..7} {13..15} {20..50..10}'
```

Result:

```
Range string: 5
Range string: 6
Range string: 7
Range string: 13
Range string: 14
Range string: 15
Range string: 20
Range string: 30
Range string: 40
Range string: 50
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solution uses `declare` which seems to have the same concern about running arbitrary code as `eval` does (according to this article: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048). If the input string is the problem, I can still change the way the series of sequences is entered.

Comment: @iND thanks, you're right. One can inject evil codes in the argument. I've updated my code, which will be a little better.